# Using jquery to scroll site causes touch gestures to stop working on Safari on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ios

I'm building a custom website using Angular, that is a single-page-app, with multiple menu sections. Selecting different menu sections triggers a scroll animation, where the page scrolls to that selected section using jquery. This all works fine and dandy on all browsers and platforms, except for Safari on iOS. On Safari on iPhone, after changing page sections, and triggering the scroll animation, all touch gestures for some reason stop working on the site. Only way to get the touch gestures to start working again is to either tap on the Safari address bar, or double-tap anywhere on the screen, after which all touch gestures start working again. This issue does not happen on any desktop browsers, or any other mobile browsers besides Safari.

Using the Mac iOS simulator, I was able to narrow the issue down to the scrolling behavior that happens when changing page sections. By disabling the scroll animation on mobile, the problem disappears, like so:

```
 if(window.innerWidth < 768){
  //for mobile
  //disable scroll animation
  document.body.scrollTop = scrollPos;
}
else{
  //use jquery for smooth scrolling on desktop
  $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
    scrollTop: scrollPos
  }, 500);
}
```

Although I was able to find a workaround, it is not ideal. Nor does it answer the question as to why using Jquery to scroll the site causes touch gestures to break on iOS Safari. Any ideas?

For reference, here's the site: [www.everythinggoods.studio](https://www.everythinggood.studio)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue here:

```
$([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
    scrollTop: scrollPos
  }, 500);
```

Should be:

```
$(document.body).animate({
    scrollTop: scrollPos
  }, 500);
```

After removing `document.documentElement` from the list of elements to scroll, I'm no longer having this issue. Still not exactly sure why this was causing tap gestures to break on Safari iOS only. But, the problem is fixed now, so that's all that matters :D

Fix is now live here: [www.everythinggoods.studio](https://www.everythinggoods.studio)